# Search many props in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

There is a table with 2 columns:

```
x    y
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    2
2    3
2    4
3    1
3    2
3    5
```

If I need to find all X, where Y = 5. I use query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE y = 5
```

But, I need to find all X, where Y = 2 AND Y = 3.

How to do this on 1 query?

In result I must to get X = 1 and 2 (NOT 3!). And Y may be many

```
If i use SELECT * FROM table WHERE y IN (1, 2)
```

I will get x = 1, 2, 3, but I **not need Y = 3** because in table no line x=3, y=3

Comment: Try my answer now beacuse if you add one more eow with X=3 and Y = 3 the @KuyaJohn's answer gives wrong result

Comment: @SaharshShah what's wrong with my answer? see this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75e8b/1

Comment: Sorry @KuyaJohn I got your logic your answer is perfect. I understand it in a wrong way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   x
FROM     tableName
WHERE    y IN (2,3)
GROUP BY X
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d8bb/1)

if unique contraint was not specified for each x, then `DISTINCT` is a must

```
SELECT   x
FROM     tableName
WHERE    y IN (2,3)
GROUP BY X
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT y) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d8bb/2)

Comment: Thank you, its relay that I need to!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE b WHERE Y = 2 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE b.X = X AND Y = 3);
```

Comment: No, I need X where Y = 2 AND 3, in your way will bee y = 2 OR 3

Comment: then simply put **and** between query. SELECT * FROM table WHERE y = 2 and y = 3

Comment: @SaharshShah it will return zero result if `AND` will be used.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `OR` to create a boolean expression in your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (y = 2) OR (y = 3);
```

If that gets tedious because of many `y` values, then use `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE y IN (2,3);
```

Comment: nope, this will get all `X` if `Y` matches to either 2 or 3. did you try this?

Comment: I don't need OR, I need **AND**

Comment: That can't be, Mary.  It is impossible for the condition `y=2 AND y=3` to be true.  `IN` is just a shortened version of a list of `OR` conditions.